# sprintf(array, "%4d\n", int), turning it back into an int

Tags: c, arrays, udp, format, printf

I'm having trouble understanding how this piece of code formats an int to a string:

```
length[16];
sprintf(length, "%4d\n", len );
length[5]=0;
UDP_Write( sd, &cli, length, 6);
```

I then need to turn length back to an int, but how? If, for example, len == 512, isn't length gonna be filled like this: 0512x0? How do I turn it back to an int if there's a character in length that I don't know of its' contents?

Comment: This code may cause buffer overflow on a 64-bit system .. sloppy coding

Comment: I guess you meant `char length[16];`

Comment: If you need the number as an `int`, then why not just send it as-is as an `int` to begin with? Why convert it to a `char[]` at all? `UDP_Write( sd, &cli, (char*)&len, sizeof(len));`

Comment: UDP_Write will send length to my program. This piece of code is in another program that I'll use have to use in mine, but I can't make it useful when sent with that format, so I'm desperately trying to convert it into an int.

Answer (score 1):

For input int `512`, the result of the code is the string `" 512\n"`.  There's no zeroes or letters in there, not sure where you got that idea from.

To convert string to int, you could use any of the usual methods, e.g. `sscanf`, `strtol` etc.  because they are able to ignore leading whitespace.